# clasificar automáticamente una lista de números en intervalos

Tags: python, pandas, datos

bien, el contexto es: tengo una lista de velocidades de viento, imaginemos,100 medidas de vientos de 0 a 50 km/h, entonces yo cargándole el csv quiero automatizar la creación de lista imaginemos, cada 5km/h, es decir los que van de 0 a 5 lo que van de 5 a 10... etc.

vayamos al codigo:

```
import pandas as pd

viento = pd.read_csv("viento.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame(viento)

x = df["Valor"]

d = sorted(pd.Series(x))

lst = [[] for i in range(0,(int(x.max())+1),5)]
```

Esto me da una lista de listas vacias, es decir si los vientos van de 0 a 54 km/h me va a crear 11 listas vacías.

ahora bien, para clasificar hice esto:

```
for i in range(0,len(lst),1):
    for e in range(0,55,5):
       for n in d:
            if n>e and n< (e+5):
               lst[i].append(n)
            else:
                continue
```

mi objetivo sería que cuando llegue a un número mayor que 5 salte al siguiente nivel es decir sume 5 a los limites del intervalo (e) y salte al siguiente i para que rellene la segunda lista vacia en lst. Lo intente de varias formas por que imagino que los bucles deben ir en un orden concreto para dar un buen resultado. este codigo es solo un ejemplo de varios que intente, pero todos me daban resultados similares, o se llenaban todas las listas con todos los numeros, o se llenaba solo la primera lista con todos los numeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu solución tiene tres bucles anidados. Cada nivel de anidación de bucle aumenta la complejidad del problema un orden de magnitud, por lo que tu solución va a tardar mucho si hay muchos datos. Además todos los bucles los realiza Python, que es lento haciendo esas cosas.

Puesto que tus datos ya están en un dataframe Pandas, lo mejor es utilizar las herramientas de Pandas para evitar escribir ningún bucle. Eso es lo que haré en esta solución. Puede que esta solución sea la más "fea" desde un punto de vista sintáctico y la más larga de explicar y comprender, pero es la más corta en tiempo de ejecución y hasta en líneas de código, pues todo se resuelve en una sola línea:

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.valor, pd.interval_range(start=0, end=50, freq=5))).apply(lambda x: list(x.valor))
```

### Explicación y demo

Empecemos por crear algunos datos de prueba y ponerlos en un dataframe como el tuyo (del cuál sólo sé que tiene una columna llamada "valor" y el resto no parecen interesar aquí):

```
import pandas as pd
# Tomo números de ejemplo de la respuesta de Marce Puente
vientos = [ 16, 18, 16, 16, 18, 42, 42, 42, 39, 3, 6, 6, 3, 4, 14, 12, 11, 11, 20, 20, 21, 44, 44, 44, 44, 43, 7, 10, 8, 25, 23, 24, 26, 26, 36, 36, 35, 30, 30, 29, 30, 31, 32, 34 ]
df = pd.DataFrame({"valor": vientos})
```

Lo primero para Pandas sería clasificar cada uno de los datos en una "categoría", según su valor. Las categorías en este caso serán los diferentes intervalos (0,5], (5, 10], (10, 15], (15, 20], etc. Así, por ejemplo, el primer dato que vale 16 correspondería a la cuarta categoría (15, 20].

Esta clasificación la hace `pandas.cut()` a la que hay que pasarle la lista de datos (`df.valor`) y  la lista de categorías. Esta última se puede crear con `pandas.interval_range()` así que tenemos ya el primer ingrediente de la respuesta:

```
pd.cut(df.valor, pd.interval_range(start=0, end=50, freq=5))
```

`pd.interval_range()` crea una serie de intervalos cada uno de tamaño 5 (`freq=5`) comenzando en 0 y acabando en 50. Los intervalos están por defecto abiertos por la izquierda y cerrados por la derecha. Esto es, un dato de valor 10 pertenecerá al intervalo (5, 10] pero no al (10, 15]. Esto puede cambiarse con parámetros apropiados en `pd.interval_range()`

`pd.cut()` clasifica todos tus datos asignando a cada uno la "etiqueta" de a qué intervalo pertenece. Por ejemplo, los primeros elementos de lo que `pd.cut()` retorna se verían así:

```
0     (15, 20]
1     (15, 20]
2     (15, 20]
3     (15, 20]
4     (15, 20]
5     (40, 45]
...
```

que significa que los cinco primeros datos estarían en el intervalo (15,20], el sexto pertenecería al (40, 45], etc...

El siguiente paso es utilizar esta clasificación para `df.groupby()`. Eso agrupará todos los datos que pertenezcan a una misma categoría. Cada grupo es en si mismo un mini-dataframe de estructura igual a `df`, o sea, las mismas columnas pero que solo tiene filas con los datos que correspondan a ese grupo.

Típicamente hay que aplicar seguidamente algún tipo de operación al grupo. Por ejemplo, si sólo quisiéramos contar cuántos elementos hay en cada categoría aplicariamos `.count()` así:

```
pd.groupby(...).count()
```

y para este caso el resultado sería:

```
valor          
(0, 5]        3
(5, 10]       5
(10, 15]      4
(15, 20]      7
(20, 25]      4
(25, 30]      6
(30, 35]      4
(35, 40]      3
(40, 45]      8
(45, 50]      0
```

Lo que te dice cuántos datos tienes en cada categoría, es decir, un histograma.

Pero en tu caso quieres no solo cuántos hay, sino cuáles son. Es decir, quieres convertir a lista de valores cada grupo. Por eso en mi respuesta aplico una función que hace eso, mediante una lambda:

```
df.groupby(...).apply(lambda x: list(x.valor))
```

y el resultado entonces es:

```
valor
(0, 5]                             [3, 3, 4]
(5, 10]                     [6, 6, 7, 10, 8]
(10, 15]                    [14, 12, 11, 11]
(15, 20]        [16, 18, 16, 16, 18, 20, 20]
(20, 25]                    [21, 25, 23, 24]
(25, 30]            [26, 26, 30, 30, 29, 30]
(30, 35]                    [35, 31, 32, 34]
(35, 40]                        [39, 36, 36]
(40, 45]    [42, 42, 42, 44, 44, 44, 44, 43]
(45, 50]                                  []
```

Si no estás interesado en el resultado como dataframe sino como lista de listas (que era lo que hacías en tu código) puedes añadir al final un `.to_list()` para obtener

```
[[3, 3, 4],
 [6, 6, 7, 10, 8],
 [14, 12, 11, 11],
 [16, 18, 16, 16, 18, 20, 20],
 [21, 25, 23, 24],
 [26, 26, 30, 30, 29, 30],
 [35, 31, 32, 34],
 [39, 36, 36],
 [42, 42, 42, 44, 44, 44, 44, 43],
 []]
```

### Conclusión

Aunque la explicación ha sido larga y la sintaxis es bastante horrible, observarás que no he escrito ni un solo bucle. Naturalmente para poder hacer lo que se le pide, Pandas sí que tendrá que hacer bucles, pero éstos están implementados en C de forma muy eficiente sobre estructuras de datos basadas en numpy y de acceso muy rápido. Va a ser muchísimo más rápido que cualquier solución que convierta el dataframe en lista y luego itere por ella. Cronometra ambas soluciones y verás la diferencia.

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de recorrer la lista completa en busca de los valores que cumplen con el rango, te recomiendo hacerlo directamente con pandas, es mucho más rápido y eficiente, yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```
import pandas as pd

viento = pd.read_csv("viento.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame(viento)

x = df["Valor"]

lst = []

step = 5

for i in range(x.min(),(int(x.max())+1),step): #Se genera un rango desde el valor mínimo al máximo con un valor de paso

  if i==x.min(): #Inicializamos los valores iniciales

    liminf = x.min()
    limsup = liminf+step-1

  val_rango = list(x[x.apply(lambda n: n>=liminf and n<limsup)]) #Se genera una lista de los números que forman parte del rango que se está evaluando usando pandas, para disminuir el tiempo de ejecución
  lst.append(val_rango) #Se guardan los valores obtenidos

  liminf+=step-1 #Pasamos al siguiente ciclo
  limsup+=step-1
```

Con un archivo de prueba, la lista quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
[[3, 6, 6, 3, 4],
 [7, 10, 8],
 [14, 12, 11, 11],
 [16, 18, 16, 16, 18],
 [20, 20, 21],
 [25, 23, 24, 26, 26],
 [30, 30, 29, 30],
 [31, 32, 34],
 [36, 36, 35],
 [42, 42, 42, 39],
 [44, 44, 44, 44, 43]]
```

Comment: **Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable **no** utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces apply podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.